# Trying to get an X.509 certificate in Android

Tags: android, rsa, keystore

I'm making in Android with the Keystore so I need to create an RSA public and private key with 3072 bit length (this length is mandatory for me, and the Android doc said that its perfectly valid).

So, my first choice to create these RSA keys (remember I need 3072 bit long) was to use [this online tool](https://www.lddgo.net/en/encrypt/rsakey) where I was able to create this two keys:

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----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-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

After that, I perform my code, where in the first part of my test I was trying to import these RSA keys to the Android's Keystore. To do that, I need to create or get an X.509 certificate, so I tried

```
// this method import the private key, this is the first part of my test

 fun importPrivateKey() {
        val keyProtection = KeyProtection.Builder(
            listOf(KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT,
                KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT,
                KeyProperties.PURPOSE_WRAP_KEY).sum()).run {

                setBlockModes(*listOf(BlockMode.ECB.value).toTypedArray())
                setEncryptionPaddings(*listOf(EncryptionPadding.RSA_PKCS1.value, EncryptionPadding.RSA_OAEP.value).toTypedArray())
                setSignaturePaddings(KeyProperties.SIGNATURE_PADDING_RSA_PKCS1)
                setDigests(KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA256)
                setKeyValidityStart(DateTime.now().toDate())
                setKeyValidityEnd(DateTime.now().plusYears(1).toDate())
                build()
        }
        // this method is the one that import the key to the keystore, but the issue is 
        // on getCertificate method.
        KeystoreWrapperUtil.importKey(privateKey3072, PRIVATE_KEY_ALIAS, getCertificate(publicKey3072), keyProtection)
    }

...

// this method get the X.509 certificate

    private fun getCertificate(certificateString : String) : Certificate {
        val certificateFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509")
        val decoded = Base64.decode(certificateString, Base64.DEFAULT)
        val inputStream = ByteArrayInputStream(decoded)
        // here´s where i´m getting the exception
        return certificateFactory.generateCertificate(inputStream)
    }


// these are the keys ( same as above )
    private val publicKey3072 = "MIIBojANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAY8AMIIBigKCAYEAmIGJKHqxEMVEb2xD4nhV\n" +
            "0Ps4lPVzvVGOO1OGOhabuZ2cDFeocpWhRUNWkswUNs0LBOG6tPRtEkiEkYerKxyk\n" +
            "i8j1vfzWMIsNeJm4Ol14D/PXXLe0r+K466DPWrrz0oZcbOhaoiP/Z8qgVCfS3hp1\n" +
            "nUgTn53qiI/VFUiIgA76HOeLI/TSnRVU3CYwz17eu3M99aTeuqkTD9Nm3JK4cVTi\n" +
            "KotaTt2D18mRvGh9UEluncJ3lGjfbOwhkEb0FXqxW339HhDyBTx1XZLJCPYbicDg\n" +
            "iucGw4lnEEoQQSjmrey7XtVZgFddNOuWpGnfLWnNi0iMo9s3d+s5qrnNk82TiEVb\n" +
            "5SaX0tKM/0Z/EHgKUz9T3O5di3Vo0wwIsbdR7DkpQvw5IOjRXE9KTW2nRyGpxFXX\n" +
            "TGv5RTJHSi2fodV3h47hNuDmh084Hm0mZrw02hsskCbpYAaUM0nw1TKx/57nbAZ2\n" +
            "LdPzeL8VZvEG647AOhGoworoj7bi24AqMX1sWArPWdszAgMBAAE="

    private val privateKey3072 = "MIIG/QIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCBucwggbjAgEAAoIBgQCVQ5sho8IQkvT4\n" +
            "MXX55O7IO8SmyL7FAa+OfGSiyVMgX6MjhAIA94YnS6wCfa+KfD1fISwUHm+C9lz5\n" +
            "ol/rRvu4xGFBSWkRXwtZJ78dN0/hp8BKEkc7qk2pS4h3twcqGbgIoSSI1R9RWm8c\n" +
            "vzuduk+fa0ZSAxos7xC+IFFDFUDFSm/5ZkjH088wyMDbtIHm3ffyZdqgI1iUw5F6\n" +
            "53+pH6ajWYTDJLkEeD6yX8xVXDOXQko73AfwqrPkgIPCzCaUKyvFEPgiA/EBmDPl\n" +
            "IHPSZQu4i+m82pJkV4IooZu6jpxDYKzC4FkidqtdvVih73ZcZuof1n2ZPtPajImN\n" +
            "cMjngfKwjqUMl9WDmIxX9amTNCPRoFGBPoS1BOsEaQduknvo83aqvJ9ReKwiKs2g\n" +
            "AIjDaY0oMpSoAeRNu5P5iMjBLQuhmUvYuQZ2CXKJSf1O7wRRZOqFNmBE1j5sTf6p\n" +
            "IiwRIUCKJvhETWZhE3vkWklzvG20vbQjhVgcTKefCNF5WYdFj3MCAwEAAQKCAYA6\n" +
            "HAnG/OPOZAfuoALX+KJlXa9fZwOt2swn4pGjNlGgZtsyNnA5RCP8JF+g0KGIfnm+\n" +
            "EUIByx+KkrL7lJVXGVliQ0HBkvzOgHwAh5LFowT8Srx3mcoVlmWJpRhJ0v19DGoz"
```

But, unfortunately when I run the code I'm getting this exception:

```
java.security.cert.CertificateException: com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLX509CertificateFactory$ParsingException: com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLX509CertificateFactory$ParsingException: java.lang.RuntimeException: error:0c0000be:ASN.1 encoding routines:OPENSSL_internal:WRONG_TAG
at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLX509CertificateFactory.engineGenerateCertificate(OpenSSLX509CertificateFactory.java:311)
```

It happens in this particular line:

```
return certificateFactory.generateCertificate(inputStream)
```

I tried to to the same with another RSA public key (of 2048 bits) and it seems to work.

I'm getting the RSA public key 3072 bits incorrectly, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: As should be clear to you by now, a public key is not the same thing as an X.509 certificate. An X.509 certificate *contains* a public key as well as much other relevant information. There are numerous articles here on Stack Overflow and other sites that will show you how to do this. Do you have something you want to do with these keys? Its probably not a good idea to generate security-critical keys on some rando website.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @President James K. Polk, this is for a test so it´s no at safety issue for us. This will run in a unitary test only. Regarding the others arcticles, I was not able to find any that suits what i´m trying to do. Do you have any ?

Comment: As you are importing the keys anway you might as well use a tool such as `openssl` to create the key pair and certificate. And you really cannot claim you cannot find code for that ;)

Comment: @MaartenBodewes, thanks for the response. I used openssl to create a public and private RSA key but still have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

So I found the issue, the mistake was that I was trying to use a public key and I needed to use a certificate instead. I found all the steps in this link https://www.scottbrady91.com/openssl/creating-rsa-keys-using-openssl